# OAuth and shared email addresses

Tags: authentication, oauth

In our application, we don't use email address as the username/login, and, as a result, we have accumulated a fair amount of accounts that have duplicate email addresses (usually husband/wife pairs who share the same address, but separate accounts in the app).

We'd like to implement OAuth logins (Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc.) as a perk for our users, and we're currently investigating options for refactoring to allow for this.

My question is - is there any way to allow for OAuth logins without forcing each of our accounts to have a unique email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my earlier answer after being provided more insight to the requirement. If I were you, I'd do it like this -

1. User clicks on Login via Facebook, and keys in his credentials.
2. My app gets the access token.
3. I'll hit the `/me` endpoint of the FB graph API to retrieve the user info and the unique user ID.
4. Once I have the unique user ID, I would then check my own DB if there is an entry for that user. If I have two entries I will give the user another popup to select the account he wishes to log in and enter the password for that. 
   (So, my database should have `<userID, list of mapped accounts>` entries.)

If the user decided to create a new account and logs in via facebook, I'd repeat steps 1-3 and create a new `<username, password>` pair and add it to the list of mapped accounts.

Add comments if you want me to elaborate.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, as "login via Google/Fb/Twitter" is exactly what I'm asking about.

Comment: I changed the answer @drrcknlsn. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Actually, this is a good approach.  Thank you, I think I'll try this out.